# PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsContainingAsset return nil if type set to Album

Tags: swift, phasset

I'm trying to access the AssetCollection Via Asset. Photo framework return nil when the code get excuted. Just for additional information: Asset is picture clicked with iPhone camera and hence, it's stored under Camera Roll.

> 77AF0C78-242A-4979-8A7B-7CFF04014C54/L0/001 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func assetCollectionForAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> PHCollection {
    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

    print(asset.localIdentifier)

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsContainingAsset(asset, withType: PHAssetCollectionType.Album, options: fetchOptions)

    //let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers([asset.localIdentifier], options: fetchOptions)

    assetCollection = collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection

    return assetCollection
}
```

if I change the type to Moment, problem goes off.

```
       let collection: PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsContainingAsset(asset, withType: PHAssetCollectionType.Moment, options: fetchOptions)
```

> Constants information from Apple documentation says:
>
> Album - An album in the Photos app.
>   Albums can be created in the Photos app or appear on an iOS device through iTunes sync.
>
> SmartAlbum - A smart album whose contents update dynamically.
>   The Photos app displays built-in smart albums to group certain kinds of related assets (see Asset Collection Subtypes).
>
> Moment - A moment in the Photos app.
>   The Photos app automatically creates moments to group assets by time and location.

It means Camera Roll under Albums is not Album but a moment? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

The Camera Roll does not have the collection type `PHAssetCollectionType.Album`

Please try with the collection type
`PHAssetCollectionType.SmartAlbum` with the subtype `PHAssetCollectionSubtype.SmartAlbumUserLibrary`